# Questions only option doesn’t fit for following posts section on mobile browser

Tags: bug, design, ipad, follow-post, mobile-chrome

On my iPad with Google Chrome as a browser “Questions only” option doesn’t fit into block for following posts section.

> [image]

Comment: The entire profile page is not yet designed in a responsive way. That is probably the root-cause of this too.